# comparing largest eigenvalue of two positive matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

I have a conjecture that for any two positive matrices(all elements are positive, nothing about positive definite or symmetry) $A$ and $B$, if $A_{ij} A_{ji}>B_{ij} B_{ji}$, while there is certain bound on the entries such that they can not be too difference. Then the largest eigenvalue of $A$ is greater than that of $B$, or their spectrum radius satisfies $r(A)>r(B)$.

I don't know whether there is a theory about it, or could it be extended to a positive linear operator. 
Say, two integral operator in $L^2(R)$ space with kernel $k_1(x,y),k_2(x,y)$ and $k_1(x,y)k_2(y,x)>k_2(x,y)k_2(y,x)$.
Thank you!

Comment: What is a positive matrix? Isn't it assumed to be symmetric?

Comment: By positive I only mean its entries are positive. Thank you for noticing me this ambiguity. I edited it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is only true for $1\times 1$ and $2\times 2$ matrices. Counterexample: take
$$
 A(t)=\begin{pmatrix} t&t&t\\t&t&t\\t&t&t\end{pmatrix},\qquad
B(t)=\begin{pmatrix} t^{3/2}&1&t^3\\t^3&t^{3/2}&1\\1&t^3&t^{3/2}\end{pmatrix},\quad t\ge0.
$$
Then, for $0<t<1$ and for any $i,j\in\{1,2,3\}$,
$$
 A_{ij}(t)A_{ji}(t)=t^2>t^3=B_{ij}(t)B_{ji}(t).
$$
On the other hand, as $t\to0$, all eigenvalues of $A(t)$ tend to $0$ and all eigenvalues of $B(t)$ tend to the eigenvalues of 
$$ 
B(0)=\begin{pmatrix} 0&1&0\\0&0&1\\1&0&0\end{pmatrix}.
$$
We have $\operatorname{det}(B(0)-\lambda E)=\lambda^3-1$, and so one of the eigenvalues of $B(0)$ is $1$. Thus, $r(B(t))>r(A(t))$ for small $t>0$.

Comment: Oops.. Thank you for this example! maybe I need more restrictions. I still believe it's true under proper circumstances, I've tried many numerical cases with very high dimensions and they all worked..

Comment: Note also that you should not speak of the "largest eigenvalue", because the eigenvalues may well be complex rather than real.

Comment: Thank you Vladimir, yet I'm only talking about positive matrices here, thus it must have a real eigenvalue which is real and equal to its spectrum radius.